# Add CSS class on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a CSS class on hover to an element using jQuery. However, the class should only be applied to the closest element with a specific class so I tried using `.next`

When I add the `.next` to my code though the class isn't added anymore (it works without that part of the code). This is the code:

```
$j('.products_overlay').hover(function(){
    $j(this).next('.hover_text').addClass('overlay_text'); 
}, function(){
    $j(this).next('.hover_text').removeClass('overlay_text');
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is the HTML

```
<div class="products_overlay">
    <a href="..." title="product1" class="product-image">
        <img src="...." alt="product1" class="hover_test" />
    </a>
    <p class="hover_text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML, please?

Comment: Some snippet or fiddle?

Comment: It sounds like `.hover_text` is not a sibling of `.products_overlay` so `next()` won't find it. We need to see your HTML to be able to help you fix this

Comment: without seeing html its hard to know, try  `$j(this).parent().find('.hover_text')`

Comment: Just added the html

Comment: `next` is for getting the siblings, and `.hover_text` is your child element, so you should use `find` instead.

Comment: @MariaL thanks. Note that you don't need to use JS code for this at all. See my answer for details.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! actually done it your way with just css now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code doesn't work as `next()` looks at siblings, yet `.hover_text` is a child of `.products_overlay`. As such you should use `find()`. You can also shorten the code using `toggleClass()`:

```
$j(function($) {
    $('.products_overlay').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.hover_text').toggleClass('overlay_text'); 
    });
});
```

That being said, given your HTML you don't need to use jQuery at all. You can achieve what you need in CSS alone:

```css
.products_overlay:hover p {
  color: red; /* place the relevant hover styling in here */
}
```

```html
<div class="products_overlay">
  <a href="..." title="product1" class="product-image">
    <img src="...." alt="product1" class="hover_test" />
  </a>
  <p class="hover_text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
$j('.products_overlay .hoverText').addClass('overlay_text');
```

or

```
$j(this).find(".hoverText").addClass('overlay_text');
```

That's because `next()` doesn't look in the descendants, but in the *next* nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `next` which only finds siblings

```
$j('.products_overlay').hover(function(){
    $j(this).next('.hover_text').addClass('overlay_text'); 
}, function(){
    $j(this).next('.hover_text').removeClass('overlay_text');
});
```

`this` in that case is the products_overlay div, so your .hover_text is a child and not a sibling.

To fix it use `find`:

```
$j('.products_overlay').hover(function(){
    $j(this).find('> .hover_text').addClass('overlay_text'); 
}, function(){
    $j(this).find('> .hover_text').removeClass('overlay_text');
});
```